# Websphere LoginModule

Tags: java, websphere, jaas

I wrote a custom LoginModule which works just fine in JBoss, however, now I need to deploy it on Websphere 7 and I just can't find the appropriate way to register the LoginModule. Does anybody know how?
It should be used just for one app, not for all apps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go to Security > Global Security > Java Authentication and Authorization Service > Application Logins

Click New, provide a name and than put the full class name of your login module.

That's it.

Make sure you have "Enable administrative security" checked under Global Security or this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

See Chapter 5 in the websphere security redbook - http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG246316/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm